# Responsive toggle is not working it can be a spelling issue but i can't find my mistake

Tags: html, css

I might just need an extra set of eyes. I think I did everything correctly
but the responsive btn doesn't contain anything when I resize the screen 
thank you.

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="Header">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
    
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    
                    </button>

      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
        <h3>Portfolio</h3>
      </a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">

        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#About" class="nav-link">About Me</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#Skills" class="nav-link">Skills</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#Experience" class="nav-link">Experience</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#Contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do hope you know that `<link>` and `<meta>` should be in the `<head>` of the [HTML document structure](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp)

You will also need to include the following scripts before the `</body>` of the document to make your [Bootstrap Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) (and other Bootstrap elements) to work properly.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Most likely the problem is in .js, but you can also exclude the `<div class="container">` and put the `<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">` link before the button, the same way it is done in the Bootstrap guide.

Comment: Thank you, Yes i just didn't include <head> tag. I had the wrong JS. yours made everything work. I didn't need to change anything else.